# How to make :hover affect a non child-element

Tags: html, css

I've tried using the `:before` and `:after` pseudos to change the information displayed when hovering over one of the radio buttons. However, due to the fact that they are not child-elements, I can not seem to make it work.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

When you hover over radio button 1, the information1 element shows.

When radio button 1 is in :checked stage, the information1 element needs to remain displayed.

The same for radio button 2.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<form method="post" action="#">
  <div class="row uniform">
    <div class="3u 12u$(xsmall)">
      <input type="radio" class="radio1" id="radio1" name="group">
      <label for="radio1"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="3u 12u$(xsmall)">
      <input type="radio" class="radio2" id="radio2" name="group">
      <label for="radio2"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
      <p class="information1">information1</p>
      <p class="information2">information2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="12u$">
      <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

/* Radio1 */

input[type="radio"].radio1 {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1+label {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #D2D2D2;
  color: #888;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(radio1.png);
  height: 156px;
  width: 106px;
  line-height: 1.725rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1:hover+label {
  border-color: #BBBBBB;
  background-image: url(radio1_hover.png);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1:checked+label {
  background-image: url(radio1_focus.png);
  border-color: #51CCA8;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1:checked+label:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #4DC29F;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #4DC29F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  left: 33px;
}

/* Radio2 */

input[type="radio"].radio2 {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2+label {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #D2D2D2;
  color: #888;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(radio2.png);
  height: 156px;
  width: 106px;
  line-height: 1.725rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2:hover+label {
  border-color: #BBBBBB;
  background-image: url(radio2_hover.png);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2:checked+label {
  background-image: url(radio2_focus.png);
  border-color: #51CCA8;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2:checked+label:after {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #4DC29F;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #4DC29F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  left: 33px;
}
```

Comment: Anyone able to help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that with a bit of javascript:

```js
function getIndex(elem, attr) {
  return $(elem).attr(attr).substr(5);
}

$('label')
  .mouseover(function(ev) {
    $('.information' + getIndex(ev.currentTarget, 'for')).show();
  })
  .mouseout(function(ev) {
    var index = getIndex(ev.currentTarget, 'for');
    if (!$('#radio' + index).is(':checked'))
      $('.information' + index).hide();
  });

$('input[type=radio]')
  .change(function(ev) {
    $('p').hide();
    $('.information' + getIndex(ev.currentTarget, 'id')).show();
  });
```

```css
.information1,
.information2 {
  display: none;
}


/* Radio1 */

input[type="radio"].radio1 {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1+label {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #D2D2D2;
  color: #888;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(radio1.png);
  height: 156px;
  width: 106px;
  line-height: 1.725rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1:hover+label {
  border-color: #BBBBBB;
  background-image: url(radio1_hover.png);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1:checked+label {
  background-image: url(radio1_focus.png);
  border-color: #51CCA8;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1:checked+label:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #4DC29F;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #4DC29F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  left: 33px;
}


/* Radio2 */

input[type="radio"].radio2 {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2+label {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #D2D2D2;
  color: #888;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(radio2.png);
  height: 156px;
  width: 106px;
  line-height: 1.725rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2:hover+label {
  border-color: #BBBBBB;
  background-image: url(radio2_hover.png);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2:checked+label {
  background-image: url(radio2_focus.png);
  border-color: #51CCA8;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2:checked+label:after {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #4DC29F;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #4DC29F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  left: 33px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#">
  <div class="row uniform">
    <div class="3u 12u$(xsmall)">
      <input type="radio" class="radio1" id="radio1" name="group">
      <label for="radio1"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="3u 12u$(xsmall)">
      <input type="radio" class="radio2" id="radio2" name="group">
      <label for="radio2"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
      <p class="information1">information1</p>
      <p class="information2">information2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="12u$">
      <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have to ask though, is it possible to achieve the same without the use of javascript?

Comment: No (AFAIK) with that HTML layout, I think it would be possible to refactor the HTML code to make it viable.

Comment: Yes, see the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only CSS solution (added code on top), changing the HTML code:

```css
.information1,
.information2 {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1:hover+label+p,
input[type="radio"].radio2:hover+label+p,
input[type="radio"].radio1:checked+label+p,
input[type="radio"].radio2:checked+label+p {
  display:block;
}


/* Radio1 */

input[type="radio"].radio1 {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1+label {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #D2D2D2;
  color: #888;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(radio1.png);
  height: 156px;
  width: 106px;
  line-height: 1.725rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1:hover+label {
  border-color: #BBBBBB;
  background-image: url(radio1_hover.png);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1:checked+label {
  background-image: url(radio1_focus.png);
  border-color: #51CCA8;
}

input[type="radio"].radio1:checked+label:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #4DC29F;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #4DC29F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  left: 33px;
}


/* Radio2 */

input[type="radio"].radio2 {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2+label {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #D2D2D2;
  color: #888;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(radio2.png);
  height: 156px;
  width: 106px;
  line-height: 1.725rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2:hover+label {
  border-color: #BBBBBB;
  background-image: url(radio2_hover.png);
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2:checked+label {
  background-image: url(radio2_focus.png);
  border-color: #51CCA8;
}

input[type="radio"].radio2:checked+label:after {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #4DC29F;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-color: #4DC29F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  left: 33px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
  <div class="row uniform">
    <div class="3u 12u$(xsmall)">
      <input type="radio" class="radio1" id="radio1" name="group">
      <label for="radio1"></label>
      <p class="information1">information1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="3u 12u$(xsmall)">
      <input type="radio" class="radio2" id="radio2" name="group">
      <label for="radio2"></label>
      <p class="information2">information2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="12u$">
      <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But the thing is, I need both information elements to be in the same place (replacing each other on mouseover). On top of that, I need the radiobuttons to be inside class="3u 12u$" and the information elements inside class="6u 12u$" for layout purposes.

Comment: That's what I meant when I said I think you need to change the HTML layout.

Comment: I'll look into what my best options are regarding my audience. For the time being, thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: placing `information1` and `information2` in the same place is possible with some tricks (e.g.: `position: absolute` or `relative`), but I don't know why you need to place them inside a certain class.

Comment: The class is to keep them next to each other from left to right and at the same time keep everything in place when the viewport changes (responsive design).

Comment: That's beyond what I can test with the code I have. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, that's kind of difficult without posting the entire website haha. But basically there are three rows next to each other. The first row from the left is radio1, the second is radio2 and the third row (so on the right side) is where information1 and information2 are stored. So when I alter the html in the way you provided, it doesn't allow me to have it like the way I have it right now, which is important for the usage of my website. I hope that makes sense, please let me know if it doesn't.